# Prove that a connected graph not having $P_4$ or $C_3$ as an induced subgraph is complete bipartite

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a connected graph not having $P_4$ or $C_3$ as an induced subgraph. Prove that $G$ is a complete bipartite graph.

I understand what a complete bipartite graph is but am not sure how to relate that to a $P_4$ graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$P_4$ must mean a $4$-vertex path (a path of length $3$), otherwise the claim is not true; the $5$-vertex cycle is a counter-example.

Let $C$ an odd cycle of smallest length (if any) in $G$.  If $c \geq 5$ then any chord (edge in $G \setminus C$ connecting two vertices in $C$) implies...

> the existence of a smaller odd-length cycle in $G$ (the chord "splits" $C$ into an odd-length cycle and an even-length cycle).  E.g.: [image]

Hence $C$ (if it exists) is an induced subgraph, and thus $C$ (and hence $G$) contains an induced $P_4$ subgraph, giving a contradiction.  Hence $C$ does not exist.

Hence $G$ contains no odd length cycles, and is thus is a connected subgraph of $K_{n,m}$ for some $n,m$.  Let the parts be denoted $N$ and $M$.

If $u \in N$ and $v \in M$, then the shortest path between $u$ and $v$ is...

> an induced path of odd length.  Since $G$ contains no induced paths of length $\geq 3$, we must have that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent.

Hence $G=K_{n,m}$.