# Connected graph G is complete bipartite iff no induced subgraph of G is a $K_3$ or $P_4$

Tags: graph-theory

Where $K_3$ is a triangle and $P_4$ is a path of 4 vertices. One implication is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674282/let-g-be-a-connected-graph-not-having-p-4-or-c-3-as-an-induced-subgraph-prove-t) the other one:

If $G$ is a connected complete bipartite graph, it cannot contain any triangle induced, because then $G$ would have a triangle too and it wouldn't be bipartite. Suppose that it has a $P_4$ induced, then since $G$ is complete it must be the case that the four vertices are connected and therefore it'd be a square not a $P_4$.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it easy to understand? This subject is very graphic so I'm a little concern with how easy to understand are written proofs.

Comment: Your statement is correct for the "If G is complete bipartite then it does not have an induced $K_{3}$ or $P_{4}$."

Comment: To be "more clear" and "less graphical" you could say that the leaf vertices of the (supposed) induced $P_{4}$ must be in opposite partitions (by coloring argument) and so must have an edge between them since $G$ is complete bipartite.

Comment: But wait, I just realized I'm confused...Why a square is not a $P_4$? $P_4$ is a path on 4 vertices and square too because all vertices are different...or a path cannot be closed?

Comment: Paths are not closed (each vertex visited once)